# Ways to Flatten A Perl Array in Scalar Context

Tags: arrays, perl

I recently started learning perl and have a question that I'm not finding a clear answer to on the Internet. say I have something like this,

```
@arr = (1, 2, 3);
$scal = "@arr"
# $scal is now 123.
```

Is the use of quotes the only way to flatten  the array so that each element is stored in the scalar value? It seems improbable but I haven't found any other ways of doing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if third-party modules ever mess with `$"` and forget to put it back to its default value (see Dave Cross's answer below), but I totally ran into a situation where the same script on two different hosts gave _two different results_ for `"@arr"`: one with spaces in between and one without. Never did track down the cause (different versions of CPAN modules, different versions of Perl?), and I ended up doing an explicit `join($delim, @arr)` instead.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) function is commonly used to "flatten" lists. Lets you specify what you want between each element in the resulting string.

```
$scal = join(",", @arr);
# $scal is no "1,2,3"
```

Comment: What if you wanted to discard everything but the first element of the array, but without having to store the array to a variable first?

Answer (score 18):

In your example, you're interpolating an array in a double-quoted string. What happens in those circumstances is is controlled by Perl's `$"` variable. From [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> $LIST_SEPARATOR
>
> $"
>
> When an array or an array slice is interpolated into a double-quoted string or a similar context such as /.../ , its elements are separated by this value. Default is a space. For example, this:
>
> `print "The array is: @array\n";`
>
> is equivalent to this:
>
> `print "The array is: " . join($", @array) . "\n";`
>
> Mnemonic: works in double-quoted context.

The default value for `$"` is a space. You can obviously change the value of `$"`.

```
{
  local $" = ':',
  my @arr = (1, 2, 3);
  my $scalar = "@arr"; # $scalar contains '1:2:3'
}
```

As with any of Perl's special variables, it's always best to localise any changes within a code block.

Comment: It is throwing warning if any value in array is 'undef'. How to resolve it?

Comment: Depends what you want to do. I can think of three obvious alternatives. 1/ Ignore the warnings. 2/ Use `grep` on the array to removed the undefined elements. 3/ Use `map` on the array to convert undefined elements to some other value (perhaps an empty string). If you need any more details, you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: This is one of the best re-statements of what's in the manual that I've seen in quite a while. And I'm not being sarcastic. Excellent answer with _just_ the right amount of useful context.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use `join` without any seperator

```
my $scalar = join( '' , @array ) ;
```

There is more than one way to do it.

Comment: Pedantically, that's not using `join()` without a separator, it's using `join()` with an empty string as the separator :-)

Answer (score 5):

in the spirit of TIMTOWTDI:

```
my $scal;
$scal .= $_ foreach @arr;
```

Answer (score -3):

Read [section *Context* in `perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context). Perl has two major contexts: scalar and list.

For example:

```
@a = (1, 1, 1);   # list context
print @a;         # list context
$count = @a;      # scalar context, returns the number of elements in @a
```

etc.

Comment: This has nothing to do with *flattening* an array.